# Select only the last inserted item related to another registry

Tags: mysql, sql

I modeled a small database for easier explanation:

```
CREATE TABLE bands (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(120) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
TYPE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE albums (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  band_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  album_name VARCHAR(120) NULL,
  rating INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL,
  insertion_date TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  INDEX albums_FKIndex1(band_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(band_id)
    REFERENCES bands(id)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
TYPE=InnoDB;
```

Now, pretending that we already have some bands and many albums registered in their respective tables, I want to select ONLY the last inserted album from each registered band.

PS: I have to use the "album.insertion_date" field to determine which album is the last inserted.

Comment: Maybe you can paste somewhere (https://gist.github.com/) small dump of your inserts? I need to perform test of query.

Comment: You tagged the question as Postgresql but your SQL clearly shows MySQL. What are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgres. It seems I exported the SQL in the wrong format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining the two tables and filtering by insertion_date and band:

```
SELECT al.*
FROM albums al
INNER JOIN bands b ON al.band_id=b.id
WHERE al.insertion_date=(
    SELECT max(insertion_date)
    FROM albums
    WHERE band_id=b.id
)
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'b.band_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Doliveras wins! congratulations, and with a good execution time (even with the database filled with 18980 registries )

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select b.name, a.album_name, a.isertion_date
  from bands b, albums a
  where a.band_id = b.id
    and a.insertion_date = (select max(a1.insertion_date) from albums a1 where a1.band_id = b.id)
```

Comment: That brings the last album from a particular band, I want to get the last album from each band in a single SQL. I think asked the wrong question lol

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have the albums' ids to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` and the possibility for the `insertion_date` to be `NULL`(as it is the default value), using insertion_date to determine the results is not the smartest thing to do but ... there you go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT band, last_album, insertion_date
FROM (
      SELECT bands.name AS band, albums.album_name AS last_album, albums.insertion_date
      FROM bands
       JOIN albums ON bands.id=albums.band_id
      ORDER BY albums.insertion_date DESC
     ) t1
GROUP BY band;
```

Comment: album_name is not in the group by clause, so mysql is free to return any album_name within the same band, it may be not the one with max insertion_date

Comment: That's not a problem when using `ORDER BY`, but it was incorrect anyway ... so I just edited it.

Comment: About the use of insertion date to pick the last registry: Unfortunately I was not the person in charge of database migration. The registries of the new database were not inserted in the same order than the registries from the old database. That sucks, but had to be done.

Comment: I can't make corrections now, since I need to keep compatibility with an older application that will be deactivated in a few months. So I have to wait before run any normalization script.